# User enter path and size as a variable in centos 7 script

Tags: linux, centos, redhat-satellite

I want to write a script that allows the user to enter a specific file path and size to use as an input to the find command.

I tried the following:

```
echo "Enter file path and size":
read userpath
read sz
find $userpath -size $sz -exec rm {} \;
```

but it results in the error

```
( find: invalid argument '-exec' to -size)
```

Comment: does this help? https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-input.php read userpath sz

Comment: no, what I want is the user to enter a  size condition

Comment: In what way is it not working the way you expect?

Comment: What issue do you have with your code? It is not clear in what specific way it is not working.

Comment: it gives me this error  ( find: invalid argument '-exec' to -size)

Comment: First get the find command working when you type it on the command line directly (not in a script). Also, is filepath meant to be a directory or a file? Typically the first argument to the find command is a directory, like .